# Image not scaling correctly in Firefox

Tags: css, image, firefox, resize

I have a 2550px x 3300px image of a document.  I scale it to 901px to 1166px using css.  Also used image width/height attributes without css. It looks great in chrome and IE but the image contents look jagged in FF (3.6).  Resizing the image itself is not an option (for good quality printing).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is resizing it to exactly 50% or 25% of the pixel size an option? That usually looks best

Comment: Resize it and link it to the original image. The page will load faster and you'll still have your print quality.

Comment: @Pekka, didn't work.  @Jimmy, that's not an option in this project.  Thanks guys!

Comment: I just did a comparison with FF 3.6.12 against IE 8.0.6001.18702, and the difference is not detectable to the naked eye. Perhaps you can post an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding the CSS tag `image-rendering: optimizeQuality;` although this should be the default. Perhaps you have another tag somewhere which is overriding the default?

From http://articles.tutorboy.com/css/resize-images-in-same-quality.html

Comment: Thanks Mark. Didn't work. I have nothing in the body but the image.  No styles either. Just a plain html page.

Comment: @pistolshrimp, not that I don't like the points, but did this really solve your problem or lead you to a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If the intention is to get a better quality when the user prints the page you could use separate style sheets for print and screen.

```
<style>
@media screen
  {
      #origImage { display:none; }
  }
@media print
  {
      #screenImage { display:none; }
  }
</style>
...
<img id="origImage" src="original.jpg" />
<img id="screenImage" src="resized.jpg" />
```